# Specify dependency outside of project root in composer

Tags: php, git, build, dependencies, composer-php

I have a directory of projects. Each of these is from a git repo.

Some of these projects are REST APIs, and I want everything specified as a project dependency, like this:

```
htdocs
|- restApi1
|- restApi2
    |- Vendor
        |-Guzzle
|- restApi3
```

So project 2 has a dependency on restApi1 and restApi3. 
What I want to do is 'git checkout' if restApi1 or restApi3 is missing when I install restApi2 and build. If it is already checked out, upon `composer install` or `update`, I want it to `git pull` and rebuild to a custom command, that's it.
Since I have these setup as projects and I might be working on a change across two projects, if I pull as a dependency in like this:

```
htdocs
|- restApi1
|- restApi2
    |- Vendor
        |- Guzzle
        |- restApi1
        |- restApi3
|- restApi3
```

I have to do work to pull my changes into their repo, work to new URLs and it disrupts my workflow.
Since I hit the projects through http on localhost, I can check out whatever version from wherever and treat everything as if it were one big project of sorts, where all my codebases appear once.

Im wondering if there is a way to do this in composer, or if this is the wrong way to go about it.
Im also willing to switch my flow if theres a better way that conflicts the above.
Ive considered writing a script to run on `htdocs` that rifles through and pulls everything, but I think specifying other projects as a dependency in the composer file reveals more info about how our internal prohjects use each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add restApi1 and restApi3 to you composer.json:

```
"require" : {
    ...
    "myproject/restApi1": "dev-master",
    "myproject/restApi3": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": {
    "myproject/restApi1": {
        "url": "https://github.com/myproject/restApi1.git",
        "type":"git"
    },
    "myproject/restApi3": {
        "url": "https://github.com/myproject/restApi3.git",
        "type":"git"
    },
}
```

Then `composer update` each time yo want new updates.

The other option is to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Ive used this approach with vhosts since I was hitting them with HTTP rather than through the autoloader, however, I did it with `require-dev`. That means I have my development copies and the ones I am using for testing completely separate, and also this way, I have an ordained method of figuring out what uses what in my applications.